# Why is fs.readFile triggering "Error: EMFILE: too many open files" and how can I fix it?

Tags: node.js

I've been using this load method on a file manager class:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
const isJson = require.main.require('../js/funcs/is-json.js');
let fileCount = 0;
module.exports = class {
  constructor() {
    this.cache = {};
  }
  // .. snip ..
  load(pathName, raw = false, cache = false) {
    if (!raw) pathName = "." + pathName + ".js";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (cache && this.cache[pathName]) {
        //console.log("returned memory cached file", pathName);
        resolve(this.cache[pathName]);
      } else {
        fileCount++;
        fs.readFile(pathName, (err, data) => {
          console.log("files read", fileCount);
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            //console.log("loaded file", pathName)
            if (isJson(data)) {
              let parsed = JSON.parse(data);
              if (cache) this.cache[pathName] = parsed;
              resolve(parsed);
            } else {
              //console.log("ignored bad JSON", data);
              resolve(false);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  // ... snip ...
}
```

And now I'm getting the error:

```
files read 8774
C:\Users\jonat\.. proj path ..\js\classes\storage.js:55
            throw err;
            ^

[Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Users\jonat\.. proj path ..\cache\v1\markets\myfilename1.json'] {
  errno: -4066,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\jonat\\.. proj path ..\\cache\\v1\\markets\\myfilename1.json'
}
```

And as you can see in the logs and code, I added a `fileCounter` variable to iterate on each `fs.readFile` call and see if I'm opening some massively high number of files, but the count appears to be at just 5 (Edit: 8774 once I moved the iterator to before the file is actually read) when the error gets logged. Also, I thought `fs.readFile` would close the files when done reading, so I shouldn't have a large number of files opened at once. What's going on here and how can I better debug / fix this?

Edit: see changes to iterator count.

Comment: Note: Changed iterator to outside the file read callback and got 8774. So it is trying to open quite a large number of files. I guess I need to slow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I know just-library solutions are usually frowned upon here, but hostly, the graceful-fs node.js module was the perfect fix here. https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs

Just installed it and replaced

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

with

```
const fs = require('graceful-fs')
```

And my code magically worked again